# Create or append additional query to URL without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create or append new queries to the URL without refresh.

**Current solution**

PHP

```
echo'<a href="" onclick="addOrUpdateUrlParam(\'doorid\', ' . $row["door_style_id"] . '); return false;">';
```

JS

```
function addOrUpdateUrlParam(name, value)
{
  var href = window.location.href;
  var regex = new RegExp("[&\\?]" + name + "=");
  if(regex.test(href))
  {
    regex = new RegExp("([&\\?])" + name + "=\\d+");
    window.location.href = href.replace(regex, "$1" + name + "=" + value);
  }
  else
  {
    if(href.indexOf("?") > -1)
      window.location.href = href + "&" + name + "=" + value;
    else
      window.location.href = href + "?" + name + "=" + value;
  }
}
```

This works perfectly for appending or creating new queries as intended. But refreshes the page on click.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: Please search for similar problems before posting new questions

Comment: Try using [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)
`history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href + '/foobar' );`

Comment: are you just trying to update the address bar?

Comment: @developer without a refresh is the important part here, at the moment the webpage refreshes on click.

Comment: I don't know the scope of your problem - what i mean is - do you need to update the address bar?  or can you store the url in a separate variable until you need to use it?  or maybe you are talking about running the query in the background - i.e. with ajax

Comment: @Gavin I'm not familiar with js history use. Would this essentially replace the use of `window.location.href = `

Comment: @developer I would need to update the address bar immediately on click

Comment: Then  i would look at @NicoHaase comment